# Django query: Can you nest Annotations?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django query where I want to group the number of test attempts by test_id and get an average among each test.

The test_attempts table logs each test attempt a user makes on a given test. I want to find the average number of attempts per test

**Here is my query:**

```
average = TestAttempts.objects.values('test_id').annotate(Avg(Count('test_id'))).filter(user_id=id)
```

I am getting the following error:
'Count' object has no attribute 'split'

Is there a way to handle this without having to write raw SQL?

UPDATE:
Here is the TestAttemt model

```
class TestAttempts(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
user_id = models.IntegerField()
test_id = models.IntegerField()
test_grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=1)
grade_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
start_time = models.DateTimeField()
seconds_taken = models.IntegerField()
taking_for_ce_credit = models.IntegerField()
ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=25L)
grade_points = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True)
passing_percentage = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
passed = models.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    db_table = 'test_attempts'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a single number, an average number of attempts over all tests? Do you have a Test model?

This will work then:

```
average = (Test.objects.filter(testattempt__user_id=id)
             .annotate(c=Count('testattempt'))
             .aggregate(a=Avg('c'))['a'])
```

If you don't have a TestAttempt → Test relationship, but only a test_id field, then this *should* work:

```
average  = (TestAttempt.objects.filter(user_id=2)
                               .values('test_id')
                               .annotate(c=Count('pk'))
                               .aggregate(a=Avg('c')))
```

but doesn't work for me on sqlite, and I don't have a proper db at hand.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks again for your help I spent a ton of time looking through docs with no luck

Comment: The TestAttempt table has no pk or relationship with the Tests table. When I try to use the second option as it looks like it groups by test_id first, then counts and averages I get a SQL error?

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT `test_attempts`.`test_id` AS `test_id`, COUNT(`test_attempts`.`id`)' at line 1")

Comment: This feels like a bug in django :( Could you put your models in your question?